# MatDialog Error: No provider for InjectionToken mat-dialog-scroll-strategy

Tags: angular-material2

By including Provider: MatDialog in the Constructur

```js
constructor(groupService: GroupService, public dialog: MatDialog) {}
```

I get following error at runtime

> Error: No provider for InjectionToken mat-dialog-scroll-strategy!

I have included the Matdialog in the "app.module.ts"
Do I need a different Provider for it and which one? I use angular-material 2.0.0b12

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to include MatDialog Module in the imports.

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
   imports :[MatDialogModule],
   ...
})
```

**Edit 2022**

You need to include MatDialog Module in the imports.

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
@NgModule({
   imports :[MatDialogModule],
   ...
})
```

Comment: thanks :) In Module.ts its MatDialogModule other than that MatDialog. Which is a little bit missleading

Comment: I struggled a lot with this one, it seems that importing this module in my own module where my component was located didn't work, I had to import it in app.module.ts !

Answer (score 8):

This error also happens if you try to open dialog of a lazy loaded module from service with `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`.

To fix it you have to either move that dialog to main module or remove `providedIn` notation and add it as `providers: []` in lazy loaded module.

Comment: I found this to be quite helpful, surprised that no one has commented on this so far.

Comment: This is the most "the Angular way" answer I've found. Thank you!

Comment: Best solution! Saved me hours of research, thanks

Comment: provides? Did you mean providers?

Answer (score 3):

**Import the dialog from import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
by adding following code to your module.ts file**

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Then import it in imports as the following can see,

```
const MaterialComponent = [MatDialogModule];
```