# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I'm getting this error when running jasmine tests on my Angular app.

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MyEditDialogComponent -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyEditDialogComponent -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'MyEditDialogComponent', InjectionToken MatDialogData ], ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 33669121, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 114688, directChildFlags: 114688, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 1, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'app-edit-ban-dialog', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent: <circular reference: Object>, renderParent: <circular reference: Object>, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 1, flags: 114688, childFlags: 0, directChildFlags: 0, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object, matchedQueryIds: 0 ...
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MyEditDialogComponent -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyEditDialogComponent -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!
```

I am importing in my component:

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
```

In the component constructor I am Injecting data to the dialog:

```
 @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {
        myData : MyData
    }
```

In my karma jasmin spec for the component I am importing:

```
import {
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDialogRef,
    MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule
} from '@angular/material';
```

In the karma/jasmine spec for the component, imports and providers in `beforeEach`:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ MyFormComponent ],
        imports: [
            MatFormFieldModule,
            MatInputModule,
            MatDialogModule,                               
        ],
        providers: [
            { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
            { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: { myData: MyData } }
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

I've tried these answers but they don't fix the issue
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706533/matdialog-error-no-provider-for-injectiontoken-mat-dialog-scroll-strategy)
[This](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8419)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edit dialog component I was passing the data object into the close method.  I removed it and the error went away.

Changed this:

```
this.dialogRef.close(myData);
```

to this:

```
 this.dialogRef.close();
```

Answer (score 51):

in my case, I imported the directives MatDialogModule, MAT_DIALOG_DATA and MatDialogRef

```
import { MatDialogModule, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

and then within `beforeEach()`:

```
imports: [ MatDialogModule],
providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
    { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
  ]
```

Comment: why we need to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing MatDialogRef and MAT_DIALOG_DATA from the karma jasmin spec, and the component you need to be dialog import like this:

```
imports: [
    DynamicModule.withComponents([YOUR_DIALOG_COMPONENT])
]
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and worked ! do this in your components constructor

```
constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
  ) {
    super();
    this.dialogData = this.injector.get(MAT_DIALOG_DATA, null);
    if (this.dialogData) {
     // do your job here
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't help, note that components that use the inject will throw an injection error if their selector is used like any other component.

This solved the same error on my project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I addded `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` in the providers and it solved it for me

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA,} from "@angular/material/dialog";



providers: [{ provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {}}, { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} }, ]
```